# Почему возникает ошибка: partially initialized module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске программы командная строка выдает ошибку:

> partially initialized module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot' (most likely due to a circular import).

Вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('9...I')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, мой создатель')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Прощай, создатель')

bot.polling()
```

Comment: partially initialized module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot' (most likely due to a circular import) а конкретно - most likely due to a circular import переводиться как скорее всего из-за кругового импорта от сюда следует что у вас скрипт где происходит всё действо  назван telebot

Comment: А так как у вас нет в вашем скрипте определённого класса TeleBot то и ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй название папки или скрипта, скорее всего они у тебя названы telebot или TelebotApi